# Restrict users to open Notes & Attachments

Tags: apex, permissions, attachment

We have Account object which is common for all the users and they can see all the attachments for this object.

Is there any way to restrict users to open Notes & Attachments? Only Account Owner and Account Team members should open the attachments related to that Account record.

Can you please help me how to achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to control visibility of notes&attachments records in Salesforce. They inherit sharing settings of their parent records.

However, some people use a workaround in a form of proxy custom object for storing attachments of target object. That way you can control the visibility of attachments by this custom object.